# Simple max() function and inner join T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have simple table which puzzles me:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T3]
(
   [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [S_Id] [int] NULL,
   [P_Id] [int] NULL,
   [level] [int] NULL,
   [Path] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In the table is data

```
id  S_Id    P_Id    level   Path
------------------------------------
1   218252  218231  1   218231
2   218271  218252  1   218252
3   218271  218252  2   218231-218252
```

**EDIT:**

I try to get the

```
ID, S_ID, P_ID, level, Path
```

on maximum length of column `Path`.

It should return id 3.

If I try to get max len from path like this:

```
select 
    b.id, a.p_id, a.s_id,
    max(len(a.path)) as Path, 
    a.path  
from 
    t3 a, t3 b
where 
    b.id = a.id
group by 
    a.p_id , a.s_id, b.id , a.path
order by 
    1
```

I get all the data, not just row with id 3, why ?

Comment: Because of the `group by`?

Comment: Is there a reason you join with the same table?

Comment: I want to have the row with the the maximum lenght in the Path and that row's ID  ,  but if i group it with ID, it will give all the shorter Paths also.

Comment: join with same table is reasonless, but it will not affect the results, no ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the max path record... Correct me if I'm wrong.

```
;WITH tmp AS (select TOP 1 id from #TaskTask3 ORDER BY LEN(path) DESC)
select t.*
from #TaskTask3 t 
inner join tmp on tmp.id = t.id
```

---

### Updates

```
;WITH tmp AS (select id, row_number() over (partition by S_Id, P_Id order by len(path) DESC) as rn from #TaskTask3)
select t.*
from #TaskTask3 t 
inner join tmp on tmp.id = t.id 
WHERE tmp.rn = 1
```

Comment: What if i want all the maximum lengths and their id's grouped only by P_id, S_id ? Ie. rows 1 and 3

Comment: Then you could use `partition`. I will back and edit my comments later.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep it simple....There are other methods (mentioned already) but I think you need to start slow... :)

```
declare @maxLen int

select @maxLen =  max(len(path))
    from t3 

select * from t3 
where len (path) = @maxLen
```

Comment: can't exclude ANY of the ID columns

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to achieve with your SQL statement?

Comment: He's trying to get single row, which contains longest path.

Answer (score 0):

To put weePee's answer in a simple way,you can use the following query:

```
select id,s_id,p_id,level  from t3 where len(path)= (select max(len(path)) from t3)
```

This is what I used to create and insert into table t3:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T3]
(
   [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [S_Id] [int] NULL,
   [P_Id] [int] NULL,
   [level] [int] NULL,
   [Path] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
insert into t3 (s_id,p_id,level,path) values (218252,218231,1,'218231'),(218271,218252,1,'218252'),(218271,218252,2,'218231-218252')
```